# Make animation in front of tab bar, objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbar, cabasicanimation

I have an CABasicAnimation of a little heart that flies across my screen.  I would like to have the animation go over a tab bar.

My problem is that the animation goes behind the tab bar and so is not visible.

How can I have the animation be visible in front of the tab bar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the view that the heart is on is behind the UITabBar view. You need to make sure the heart view is always the top view.

Try:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
heartView.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response however, heartView still disappears behind the UITabBar.

Comment: @fonz101 Sorry about that. Have you tried `[self.view insertSubview:heartView atIndex:[[self.window subviews] count]];` when you create the `heartView` in your view controller? If that does not work, maybe post your code, otherwise we are shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Mathew S.  Thank you for the generous help.  I will post my code and solution shortly, once I refine it.  Essentially I created a second view where the animation terminates, and from there created timing so that it was seamless.  I did take your route of adding the view as a subview to the window,